# How can i add specific JSON value to another array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode

I'm new in IOS programming.
I have a json array described with code below.

```swift
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? 
     NSDictionary
print("json: \(String(describing: json))")
```

Output of code is;

```
json: Optional({
vendors =     (
            {
        firm = "XXX firm";
        id = 1;
        "show_firm" = 1;
    },
            {
        firm = "ZZZZZ firm";
        id = 2;
        "show_firm" = 1;
    }
  );
})
```

I want to add only firm values to another array like firms = ["XXX firm" , "ZZZZZ firm"]

How can I do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

@witek bobrowski asked String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) output.This output is below also. By the way json data comes from server as http post response.

```
json2: Optional("{\"vendors\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"firm\":\"XXX firm\",\"show_firm\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"firm\":\"ZZZZZ firm\",\"show_firm\":\"1\"}]}")
```

Comment: could you please try printing `String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)` instead of your current print statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question again. There are 2 answers given but i didn't use any of these in my code. May be these two answers are usable but because of i'm new in IOS i couldn't use any of them. At the end of long google search i solved my problem as below.

```
let vendors = json!["vendors"]! as! [[String : AnyObject]]
                
                for firm in vendors {
                    let firm1 = firm["firm"]! as! String
                    self.providerArray.append(firm1)
                   
                }
```

I hope this answer solves someone else's problem like me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to go is to decode the JSON and then add the firms value to an array.

```
struct model: Decodable{
   var vendors: [decodingModel]
}

struct decodingModel: Decodable{
    var firm: String
    var id: Int
    var show_firm: Int
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do{
    let result = try decoder.decode(model.self, from: jsonData)
    let firmsArray = result.vendors.compactMap({$0.firm})
}catch{
    print(error)
}
```

Since you have not posted your son structure, I can only assume you have a Json where vendor is an array of jsons. `firmsArray` is what you are looking for.
If this doesn't work is probably because of the wrong `model` and `decodingModel`. If you post your json structure, I will update the code so that you can properly decode your json

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to create Decodable Model for your json as below:

```
struct Firm: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let showFirm: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name = "firm"
        case showFirm = "show_firm"
    }
}
```

I created this factory method to simulate your json response locally based on what you provided in the question

```
struct FirmFactory {
    static func makeFirms() -> [Firm]? {
        let json = [
            [
                "firm": "XXX firm",
                "id": 1,
                "show_firm": 1,
            ],
            [
                "firm": "ZZZZZ firm",
                "id": 2,
                "show_firm": 1,
            ],
        ]

        // you should use the following code to decode and parse your real json response 
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(
                withJSONObject: json,
                options: .prettyPrinted
            )
            
            return try JSONDecoder().decode([Firm].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

now you will be able to map only the firm names as you request you can test like this

```
 let firmNames = FirmFactory.makeFirms()?.map { $0.name }
 print("firmNames \(firmNames)")
```